# 3rd Level <ul> isn't responding to CSS

Tags: css, navigation, html-lists

Hi so I have this code and I am unable to spot why it isn't responding to the css I am providing, I tried jsfiddle but I have no clue on what to look for.

Heres the css maybe someone can tell me why the 3rd and 2nd level ul isn't responding

```
.nav-menus {height:auto;float:right;position:absolute;display:block;right:0;clear:both;}
#access {float:right;margin: 0px;right:0;height:78px;   }
#access .menu-header, div.menu {margin-left: 12px;background-color: #fff;}
#access .menu-header ul, div.menu ul {list-style: none outside none;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
#access .menu-header li, div.menu li {display: inline;list-style: none outside none;float: left;margin: 0 .5px;position: relative;}
ul#menu-header-menu li a {display: block;height:43px;padding:30px 15px 0 15px;}
ul#menu-header-menu li a:hover {  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) inset;background-color:#fafafa;}
#access a {display: block;position: relative;height:68px;text-decoration:none;}
#access ul.sub-menu li:first-child {border:none;}
#access ul.sub-menu li { background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03) inset; margin-bottom: 1px;border-top:1px solid #ddd;font-size:11.5px;margin:0;line-height:18px; }
#access ul.sub-menu li:last-child {border-bottom:none;}
#access ul ul ul.sub-menu {border:1px solid #ddd;border-radius:2px;margin-left:5px;}
#access ul.sub-menu {border-bottom-left-radius:2px;border-bottom-right-radius:2px;border:1px solid #ddd;display:none;left: 0;position: absolute;top: 78px;} 
#access ul ul {position: absolute;top: -9999em;}
#access ul ul li:hover ul { margin-left:180px;top:0; }
#access ul ul li {min-width: 160px;}
#access ul ul li ul { right: 100%; top: -2px; }
#access ul ul ul {right:160px;top: 0;position:relative;}
#access ul ul a {line-height: 1em;padding: 10px;min-width: 160px;font-weight:normal;text-transform:capitalize;height: auto;display:block;}
#access ul.sub-menu li:hover > a {background-color:#F9f9f9;}
#access ul li:hover > ul {display: block;}
#access ul.sub-menu li.current-menu-item > a, #access ul.sub-menu li.current-page-item > a, #access ul.sub-menu li.current-ancestor-item > a, #access ul.sub-menu li.current-menu-parent > a, #access ul.sub-menu li.current-menu-ancestor > a, #access ul.sub-menu li > a:hover {border-top:1px solid #ececec;border-bottom:1px solid #ececec ;border-right:none;border-left:none;}
#access ul li.current_page_item > a, #access ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a, #access ul li.current-menu-item > a, #access ul li.current-menu-parent > a {z-index:10;  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);background-color:#fafafa;border-top:1px solid #eee;border-right:1px solid #ddd;border-left:1px solid #ddd;}
* html #access ul li.current_page_item a, * html #access ul li.current-menu-ancestor a, * html #access ul li.current-menu-item a, * html #access ul li.current-menu-parent a, * html #access ul li a:hover {}
```

heres the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qbr8c/

Comment: Do you have a link to the jsfiddle?  Would be easier to solve if we saw the html code as well

Comment: That is a lot of very unreadable code to trawl through...

Comment: oh yes sorry I didn't post link http://jsfiddle.net/qbr8c/

Answer (score 2):

What's happening to the 3rd and 2nd level ULs? Are they inheriting the styles from the 1st UL?

It's likely an issue with specificity.

```
#access .menu-header ul
```

is more specific than

```
#access ul ul
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I didn't expect such a fast one. I posted the fiddle too.